# Is there a way to transfer MSWord numbering bullets to MSExcel column?

Tags: excel, ms-word

I have been using MSWord 2010 to compose list of questions. These questions are organized in single MSWord document, using numbering - 1. first question, etc...

I was wondering could contents of each bullet be transffered to MSExcel cell? So if i have 20 questions, i would have cell with 20 rows, each containing one question.

I am asking this because i have 300 questions that i want to import to excel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to copy your numbered bullets from Excel to Word and then break them up using Excel worksheet functions.  However, it's real easy to just do it with the built-in Excel commands.

In Word:

- Increase the width on the hanging indent on your numbered list. It will make the conversion in Excel easier to deal with.
- Select your bullets and copy them.

In Excel:

- "Paste Special" the copied text into Excel using the Match Destination Formatting option.
- Select the cells you pasted the bullets by the number of digits in the bullets (i.e., first do 1-9, then do 10-99, etc.)
- With the cells selected, choose the Text to Columns command from the Data tab on the ribbon.
- Make sure that the 'Fixed Width" radio box is selected on the dialogue box that comes up, then move to the next step.
- Adjust the break lines so that there are three fields: one with the number + period, another the spaces between the numbers and text, the third the text.
- Moving to the next step - select the second field (the spaces) and click the "Do not import column (skip) radio button.
- Click finish and the bullets are imported.

Comment: This would work, but for some reason Excel is selecting a dozen or more column markers that it's pre-decided are good split candidates. I'd have to double click on each tiny one, twice, to fix Excel's mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is best if you have an already established list. The best workflow I've found for this is to create a table to work in, in word. That table then copies perfectly into cells in excel, allowing you to create a structure that will pass between the tow docs seamlessly.